# Want to highlight if certain condition match with full output in linux

Tags: linux, linux-disk-free

**I want to highlight the Use% column if it reaches above 80. Any color is fine but I want it with full output.**

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  6.3G  4.0K  6.3G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  6.3G  1.1G  5.2G  18% /run
tmpfs                  6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/os-root    9.5G  7.1G  2.0G  79% /
/dev/mapper/os-var      60G   37G   21G  65% /var
/dev/mapper/os-varlog   15G   11G  3.4G  77% /var/log
/dev/vda3              197M  173M   25M  88% /boot
tmpfs                  1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /run/user/0
```

**For example, in my case,**

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  6.3G  4.0K  6.3G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  6.3G  1.1G  5.2G  18% /run
tmpfs                  6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/os-root    9.5G  7.1G  2.0G  79% /
/dev/mapper/os-var      60G   37G   21G  65% /var
/dev/mapper/os-varlog   15G   11G  3.4G  77% /var/log
**/dev/vda3              197M  173M   25M  88% /boot** -->* 88% color should change here.*
tmpfs                  1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /run/user/0
```

**is it possible? or not? please help me guys. Sorry for my bad English.**

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it's not a helpful comment https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372285/flagging-snarky-comments-to-is-it-possible-questions

Comment: Criticism taken, so let me rephrase this. The Q just states a goal and asks whether this can be achieved. In and of itself, such yes/no questions don't make good questions here, [ask] provides more details. Further, there is no context given, like e.g. the programming language, which would be required for a programming question, obviously. All in all, my suggestion is to start, make an effort and then ask specific questions with the gathered exeperience as context. In addition to that, I would suggest taking the [tour] and also to read the descriptions of the applied tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
df -h |
    perl -anE '
        (my $p = $F[4]) =~ s/%//;
        if ($p >= 80) {
            system("tput setaf 1");
            print;
            system("tput sgr0")
        }
        else {
            print
        }
    '
```

Or with just [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
df -h | 
    while read line; do
        if [[ $line =~ (100|[8-9][0-9])% ]]; then
            tput setaf 1
            echo "$line"
            tput sgr0
        else
            echo "$line"
        fi
    done
```

Or even with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
df -h |
    awk '
        NR==1{print;next}
        {
            p=$5
            p=gensub(/%/, "", 1, $5)
            if (p>=80) {
                system("tput setaf 1")
                print
                system("tput sgr0")
            }
            else print
        }
    '
```

---

The basic idea is to use `terminfo` database to not hardcode terminal escape sequences.

I use `tput` with the sequence names from `man terminfo` to get the right code in terminal.

Eg.

```
red=$(tput setaf 1); echo "Hello ${red}world!"
```

more info at http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. I appreciate your efforts, and now I have a clear understanding of the topic. Your assistance has been invaluable. Would it be possible to reach out to you again in case I have any queries in the future? I appreciate your willingness to help and value your expertise. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I encountered an issue. When it reached 100, it did not get highlighted. The code you provided only highlights between 80-99%, but not 100%.

Comment: one more query, for the last cmd that you provided with awk, I am getting the below error:
awk: line 14: function gensub never defined

Comment: Forget the `awk` command or use `GNU awk` that implements `gensub`.  For 100, post edited accordingly.